# Designing Data Types for ASP.Net Core Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Learning ASP.NET Core. Am confused about designing data types for views.

It seems to me that a data type must include "everything that comes before, and everything that comes after" in a single type.

I have a page that displays a dynamic list of accounts located using a search from a foregoing page. The page allows the user to click on an individual account, and go to an account detail page.

To get things to work, I welded an Account property onto my SearchResult class.

And it works, but it seems quite hacky. Am I looking at the issue incorrectly, or is that how things generally go?

Comment: The class the binds to the view is called the ViewModel. It is in most cases a complex object that encapsulates the data/information needed to display to the user.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview

Comment: I see now. You create a ViewModels folder inside your Models folder. Then, instead of building classes that represent sensible abstractions, you create "amalgam classes" (my term) inside the ViewModels folder which represent whatever data particular views need to use. Great!